# Python Facebook access_token using mechanize redirect

Tags: python, facebook, redirect, mechanize

i'm building a python app that is using a login interface to automatically sign in to facebook by passing the users login data directly. Main Goal is to get the access_token from facebook.

the facebook login skript looks like this:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv( True )
br.set_handle_gzip( True )
br.set_handle_redirect( True ) 
br.set_handle_referer( True )
br.set_handle_robots( False )

br.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1)
br.addheaders = [ ( 'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1' ) ]

user = 'me@mymail.com'
password = 'myPass'

# note that client_id is pseudo-nr
url = 'https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789012345&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token'

#Open URL and submit
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['email'] = user
br.form['pass'] = password
br.submit()

result = br.geturl()
print result
```

Actually the script is working pretty fine, but there seems to be a redirecting problem after

```
br.submit()
```

When logging in to the given URL via Firefox, after manually adding username/password and pressing the submit button, the following URL is called:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.0%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26response_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3D123456789012345%26ret%3Dlogin&lwv=100
```

this is the same URL, that is given by br.submit() command.

unfortunately Firefox is performing another redirect, first to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&response_type=token&client_id=123456789012345&ret=login&ext=143846220&hash=KefDdKCLQeJo_hJR
```

followed by the final destination:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=CAAGXPLMhY0cYMlFbAPXJnPKtEPPQCP4NNZCyJkiRLE1B0iHeK6KonmgsyrzQu4uJbfe1TDV1YrmtyFb3SuYJAVhZBazHDr49oYh3i5WThZAfgTDmtHFsmpvn3ZBpeJ3NR718Dn9rm0PX4ZCpsBA6wAItUdHDcAiOZBIZACliuVEefqseFXtqCNFN2ZC9UGslohsZD&expires_in=3780
```

I don't know why mechanize is not performing this redirect. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: i have multiple VM's for testing an app which needs the access_token. As you might understand i don't want to do the login manually 10 times a day.